# Which article fits better in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles

> Please read **the** instruction(s) in exercise 1.

or

> Please read **an** instruction in exercise 1.

Comment: I like the first one better.  Unless (in the second one) the exercise has many instructions, and we are being requested to read just one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the convention is to use:

> Please read the instruction(s) in exercise 1.

So I recommend this.

In the second sentence:

> Please read an instruction in exercise 1.

"**an** instruction" implies that you are allowing the reader to simply choose *any* instruction in exercise 1 and start reading it. In most cases, this is not so. Usually when you are telling someone to read an instruction, you are talking about a *specific* instruction and not requesting him / her to just pick any random guideline or instruction and start reading it.